# Infinite scroll in React with previously changed setState not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, infinite-scroll, setstate

I have a React component which gets from an API data with fetch of 10 images. I would like to use **infinite scroll** to load more sets of 10 images.

What I made to do is to **listen the event of reaching the bottom of the website and posting new url of nest 10 images in console only** :)

Should I focus on getting all data in my url, or focus on render and usage of related function?

Or maybe the problem is because I get data in componentDidMount and I don't know how to update whole state?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ViewSection extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            image: [],
            like: [],
            location: [],
            first_name: [],
            last_name: [],
            pictureId: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
            page: 1
        };
        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this) // I'M MOVING DATA TO HANDLE SCROLL
    };

    handleScroll(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        let documentHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
        let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        let windowScroll = window.scrollY;
        let scrollTotal = windowScroll + windowHeight;

        if (scrollTotal == documentHeight) {   

            this.setState({  page: this.state.page + 1  })
            // console.log(this.state.page);
        }
    };

    componentDidMount() {


        let urlImage = ('https://api.website.com/categories/' + this.props.params.sectionId +  '/photos/?client_id=MYID&page=' +    this.state.page); // MAP ALL PAGES?????

        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll,false); 

        fetch(urlImage)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(response => {

            // console.log(response);
            // console.log(this.state.page);

            let arrayOfImages = response.map((item) => item.urls.small );
            let arrayOfLikes = response.map((item) => item.likes );
            let arrayOfLoc = response.map((item) => item.user.location );
            let arrayOfFirst_Names = response.map((item) => item.user.first_name );
            let arrayOfLast_Names = response.map((item) => item.user.last_name );

            this.setState ({
                image : arrayOfImages,
                like : arrayOfLikes,
                location : arrayOfLoc,
                first_name : arrayOfFirst_Names,
                last_name : arrayOfLast_Names
            })
        });
    };

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll,false);
    };

    render() {

        // console.log(this.state.image);
        console.log(this.state.page); // LISTENS AND RENDERS ALL CHANGES... MAYBE PROMISE.ALL ON    urlImage...?

        let section = this.state.image.map((elem, i, page) => {

            return (
                <Link key={i}  onScroll={this.handleScroll} className="section-picture" to= {`/section/${this.props.params.sectionId}/picture/${this.state.pictureId[i]}`}>
                    <img className="image" src={elem} alt="" />
                     <div className="section-picture-stats">
                        <div className="section-picture-stat"> author: {this.state.first_name[i]}   {this.state.last_name[i]}</div>
                        <div className="section-picture-stat">{this.state.like[i]}  like(s)</div>
                        <div className="section-picture-stat">{this.state.location[i]}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            )
        });

        return (
            <div className="gallery">
                <h1>Section</h1>
                <div className="buttons">
                    <div className="sort-clicks click">sort by: <a className="click" href="">new</a>    or <a className="click" href="#">trending</a></div> <Link className="click"    to='/'>back</Link>
                </div>
                <div className="section-picture-list">{section}</div>
            </div>
        )
    };
};

export { ViewSection }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the value of `section` will be the result of mapping an empty array, since `this.state.image` will be empty until the fetch in componentDidMount finishes. Try adding a check in your render function like so:

```
let section;
if (this.state.images.length === 0) section = <p>Loading...</p>;
else section = this.state.image.map((elem, i, page) => {
  ...your code goes here...
});
```

This way it should update properly at least on the initial render

Comment: Ha! This looks promising! But still, this doesn’t work.<br>
I checked how **this.state.image** is working and here are my thoughts. At first attempt, console.log shows “this.state.image.length” = 0 in both cases below.<br><br>

1. If I have commented this line<br>
<pre><div className="section-picture-list">{section}</div><code><br>
after a while, console.log shows **10**. Cool!<br><br>

2. But with the line above, when I normally try to render the images debugger says:** “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined”**.... :(

Comment: Sorry for awful formatting, I tried to look this the best way possible :) I'm new in here.